# SSL handshake failure error despite importing certificates in java cacerts

Tags: java, eclipse, rest, ssl

I'm trying to GET some data using a REST api. I am using apache's http client for it.However, whenever I try to connect it shows me an 'SSL handshake failure'

What I did was:
1. From chrome, download the certificates for the website. It has 3 certificates in the following hierarchy

```
-- Cert 3
  --Cert 2
    -- Cert 1
```

2. Next i ran this command inside my securities folder under Java JRE

`keytool -keystore cacerts -importcert -alias para1 -file Cert1.cer`
`keytool -keystore cacerts -importcert -alias para2 -file Cert2.cer`
`keytool -keystore cacerts -importcert -alias para3 -file Cert3.cer`

This step was successful

3. I closed and reopened Eclipse, however the error doesn't go away.

   - Is there some refresh function in eclipse that I am missing that will make use of the updated keystore?
   - Or am i supposed to import the whole chain and link them somehow instead of importing each of them individually.

Here is the stack trace:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.recvAlert(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecord(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpConnection.flushRequestOutputStream(HttpConnection.java:828)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.writeRequest(HttpMethodBase.java:2116)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.execute(HttpMethodBase.java:1096)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeWithRetry(HttpMethodDirector.java:398)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeMethod(HttpMethodDirector.java:171)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:397)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:323)
    at Upload.get(Get.java:124)
    at Upload.main(Get.java:63)
```

Comment: May be trivial, have you double checked the JRE running eclipse and the JRE where you have installed the certificates? Be sure are the same

Comment: Yes they are the same! Thanks

Comment: `handshake_failure` is not because the certificates are not in the truststore. It should be `javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed`. Please debug with -Djavax.net.debug=all.

Comment: @pedrofb Thanks for shedding light on it. I was using Jre 1.7 and I updated it to 1.8 and the program worked. However, I would like to know whats the issue between these two, I will try what you said

Comment: In Java 1.7  TLS1.2 is available but not enabled. In Java 1.8 TLS1.2 is enabled  by default. Also cacerts truststore could have different certificates. It's hard to tell without seeing traces for 1.7 and 1.8